# Laptop screen Dims after getting unplugged, can not change it unless with a reboot Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, 22.04, screen, brightness

Anytime I unplug my laptop it gets dimmed, however even if I press the brightness keys or change the brightness slider OR PLUG IN my laptop, it will not change, the only way to get it back to normal is by restarting the laptop. I cannot find a fix, this started happening a few months ago. I also use an RTX 3050.